# Truncate a column that is the result of CONCAT function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to truncate a column that I have created in my query to display only 15 characters, however I don't know how to. In a table (yes), in a query (no).

How would I write my code to do this? Here's the code:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(StudLName, ',',UPPER(StudFName)) AS StudentName FROM STUDENT);
```

Current result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
(SELECT LEFT(CONCAT(StudLName, ',',UPPER(StudFName)),15) AS StudentName FROM STUDENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the CONCAT function in a LEFT function

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `LEFT`, using a cast:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(StudLName, ',', UPPER(StudFName)) AS CHAR(15)) AS StudentName
FROM STUDENT;
```